# ¿Cómo puedo formular una regla, un check o algo que me ayude con estos problemas?

Tags: sql, sql-server

muy buenos días tengo el siguiente problema agregar una restricción, regla etc. para que al momento de agregar información a la tabla vendedor solo me deje hacer lo siguiente

La tabla vendedor con información del vendedor la cual incluya el correo electrónico, que
debe integrar el arroba como carácter intermedio, el teléfono que debe iniciar con los números
664, 665 o 686.

la tabla es la siguiente:

```
 create table Vendedor 
    (

Idvendedor int,

NombreVen varchar(50),


CorreoVen varchar(50),

TelefonoVen bigint

)
```

Intente lo del numero telefónico de la siguiente manera:

```
alter table Vendedor add constraint ck_Tel check (TelefonoVen like ('%[664]','%[665]','%[686]'))
```

también de la siguiente manera:

```
alter table Vendedor add constraint ck_Tel check (TelefonoVen like ('%[664]','%[665]','%[686],[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]'))
```

ninguna de esas me funciono, igual con las reglas, no pude agregar nada, muchas gracias por leerme, espero puedan ayudarme a solucionar este problema

Answer (score 2):

.- Para el `email`:

```
Alter table Vendedor
add constraint ck_Correo check (CharIndex('@',CorreoVen) between 2 And (len(CorreoVen)-1));
```

Validando que el Correo contenga una **@** porque `CharIndex` devolverá un número mayor que **0** si la encuentra. Como dices intermedio, pues que ocupe ese resultado entre **2** y la longitud del valor **-1**.

.- Para el `Vendedor`:

```
Alter table Vendedor 
add constraint ck_Tel check (left((cast(TelefonoVen as varchar(10))),4) like ('66[456]_'))
```

*Que inicie*, por tanto su longitud es *mayor de 3* caracteres. Utilizando `like('66` los **2** primeros son obligatorios como un dígito **6**.

El tercero es cualquiera de entre los elegidos.

El cuarto es un dígito cualquiera. Tiene que ser un número porque el destino es un BigInt, pero es obligatorio y cualquiera.

Luego, si deseas dotar de una longitud obligatoria/mínima, podrías añadir el número de caracteres subrayado requeridos y cambiar el left (expresión, 4)  por el número de caracteres mínimo elegido.

```
--Validando correo
Insert into Vendedor (Idvendedor, NombreVen, CorreoVen, TelefonoVen) values (1,'a','correo@bueno.com',6650000);
Insert into Vendedor (Idvendedor, NombreVen, CorreoVen, TelefonoVen) values (2,'b','@bueno.com',6650000);
Insert into Vendedor (Idvendedor, NombreVen, CorreoVen, TelefonoVen) values (3,'c','correo@',6650000);
Insert into Vendedor (Idvendedor, NombreVen, CorreoVen, TelefonoVen) values (4,'d','correobueno.com',6650000);
Insert into Vendedor (Idvendedor, NombreVen, CorreoVen, TelefonoVen) values (5,'e',null,6650000);
Insert into Vendedor (Idvendedor, NombreVen, CorreoVen, TelefonoVen) values (6,'f','',6650000);
```

[image: Resultado]

Solo inserta si el texto contiene una **@** en cualquier posición que no sea, *ni la primera, ni la última*, o **null**, ya que el campo no está definido como `Not Null`.

```
--Validando Telefono
Insert into Vendedor (Idvendedor, NombreVen, CorreoVen, TelefonoVen) values (7,'g',null,7650);
Insert into Vendedor (Idvendedor, NombreVen, CorreoVen, TelefonoVen) values (8,'h',null,6750);
Insert into Vendedor (Idvendedor, NombreVen, CorreoVen, TelefonoVen) values (9,'i',null,6640);
Insert into Vendedor (Idvendedor, NombreVen, CorreoVen, TelefonoVen) values (10,'j',null,6650);
Insert into Vendedor (Idvendedor, NombreVen, CorreoVen, TelefonoVen) values (11,'k',null,6660);
Insert into Vendedor (Idvendedor, NombreVen, CorreoVen, TelefonoVen) values (12,'l',null,665);
Insert into Vendedor (Idvendedor, NombreVen, CorreoVen, TelefonoVen) values (13,'m',null,664 );
```

Solo inserta si contiene **664** o **665** ó **666** y tiene al menos un dígito más, o **Null** ya que en la definición de la tabla no se ha aplicado `Not Null`

[image: Resultado]

[CharIndex](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/sql/t-sql/functions/charindex-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)

[Like](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/sql/t-sql/language-elements/like-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)

[Len](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/sql/t-sql/functions/len-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)

Comment: Muchas gracias, le agradezco me ayudo bastante, ahora entiendo mejor, tenia la idea de como hacerlo pero me faltan algunas cosa, muchas gracias

Answer (score 0):

Tienes dos problemas en lo que has intentado:

- Estas tratando `TelefonoVen` como si fuera una cadena, lo digo por el `like`, pero lo cierto es que esta columna es un `bigint`
- La sintaxis del `like` es invalida, solo se puede  comparar contra un único parón, eventualmente podrías hacer: `col like 'patron1' or col like 'patron2'`

Lo que si puedes hacer es convertir la columna a un `varchar` y obtener los 3 primeros caracteres y compararlos mediante un `in` con los tres posibles valores:

```
create table Vendedor (
  Idvendedor int,
  NombreVen varchar(50),
  CorreoVen varchar(50),
  TelefonoVen bigint check (LEFT(CONVERT(VARCHAR, TelefonoVen),3) IN ('664','665','686'))
)
```

Comment: gracias por su aporte, le agradezco infinito